# Android Studio Error Create New Project in Default Project Location After open Project in other directory

Tags: android

Android Studio Error Create New Project in Default Project Location

Hello all, Please I need Help.

I have Android Studio in my notebook and success create new project.
default location project in `C:\Users\RELION\AndroidStudioProjects`

Then, I try to open project from other location (example in D:) directory.

after that, I try to create new project and project location setting I change, I directed to default location , that is 
`C:\Users\RELION\AndroidStudioProjects`

but , an error message appears : 'AndroidStudioProjects' already exists at the specified project location.

even I try to change project location , still an error message appears : 'DIRECTORY_NAME' already exists at the specified project location.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R33vT.jpg)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpbaZ.jpg)
[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4gZz.jpg)
[Screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0Ycb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is asking you to choose the name of a **New Folder** for the project.

You just need to provide the path to a **new** folder, one which does still not exist.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have already created a project **"TestNewProject"** in your default directory **"AndroidStudioProjects"** with out any folder named **"TestNewProject**" and that's why its asking for you to make a new folder with another name. if you have already created the project directly in your default directory without the folder of a project name then find and delete the project files of your project from **"AndroidStudioProjects"** and then give a path in android studio as **"C:\users\RELION\AndroidStudioProjects"** . in my case it worked.

otherwise just make a folder by some other name like **"TestNewProject1"** in your default directory **"C:\users\RELION\AndroidStudioProjects"** and then set path in your project save location. it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a subfolder where you are going to save the project.

When navigating to the location, you have to create a subfolder using Android Studio.
Your prefered project storage location here is `C:\Users\RELION\AndroidStudioProjects`, proceed to create a subfolder, using Android Studio (while navigating), like `C:\Users\RELION\AndroidStudioProjects\CalculatorProject`